# The reason of ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT error in Express.js middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have created middleware to validate fields in body, here is how it looks like:

Front-end route:

```js
router.post('/s-i', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.post('/sign-in', req.body)

    res.cookie("_rt", data._rt, { httpOnly: true, secure: false })
    delete data._rt

    return res.json(data)
  } catch (e) {
    // Here is error
    return res.status(e.response.status).json(e.response.data)
  }
});
```

Route (back-end):

```js
router.post('/sign-in', v(['email', 'password', 'twoFa', 'phone']), wrapAsync(userController.signIn));
```

Middleware:

```js
exports.v = fields => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    fields.forEach(field => {
      if (req.body[field]) {
        const result = require(`./validators/${field}`)(req.body[field])
        if (!result)
          return res.status(400).json({ message: 'bad-request', status: 400 })
      }
    })
    next()
  }
}
```

In the place where comment is placed I can see this error, actually, everything works find, and if there is wrong field in body front will receive 400 status code, but in back-end terminal I still have this error and can't get why.

The problem is I still keep getting this `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT` error. I know the reason of this problem - for example - if you are trying do `res.send({})` twice, but I don't really see the reason of problem in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return res.status(400)...` statement returns only from the inner function `fields.forEach(field => {...})`, but you must return from the middleware function, otherwise the `next()` will invoke subsequent middlewares after the `.json` output, leading to the observed error.

You can achieve this by replacing `fields.forEach(field => {...})` with

```js
for (var field of fields) {
  if (req.body[field]) {
    const result = require(`./validators/${field}`)(req.body[field])
    if (!result)
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'bad-request', status: 400 })
  }
}
```